# is there a way to calculate lines of code from executable / .so files?

Tags: linux, lines-of-code

In linux, is there a way to calculate lines of code from executable / .so files ?

I am aware of calculating using cloc, but that applies only on the code directory.

But I need to be able to calculate from either the executable / .so files, to get the effective lines of code.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible if you need the count of C/C++ code.  Even if you had a way to decompile the code, it'd be after the optimizer ran, so that's not representative of the actual code developers are working in.  Your best option is probably to use a disassembler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, it is for C code. Also, I was wondering if anything might be possible with help of GDB ?

Comment: gdb can disasemble (although the command escapes me; use google).  I'm not aware of anything that decompiles to any degree of usefulness.